# Retrive all BLOB images from Android SQLite Database

Tags: android, sqlite, opencv, android-studio, bitmap

I have a code to save pictures taken from the camera to a SQLite Database in the BLOB format, and I can display one image in an ImageVIew. How can I get all the BLOBs from the database and convert all of them into bitmaps for later convert them again into the OpenCV's Mat format?

MainActivity:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 1888;
    public ImageView imageView;
    Imagehelper help = new Imagehelper(this);

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        this.imageView = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

        Button B = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.camera);
        B.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(
                        android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
            }
        });
    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST) {
            Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            photo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100 , stream);
            byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
            help.insert(byteArray);

        }
    }
}
```

ImageHelper:

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class Imagehelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "clothes.db";
    private static final int SCHEMA_VERSION = 3;

    public Imagehelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, SCHEMA_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE Image(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,imageblob BLOB, text_to_audio TEXT);");
    }


    public void insert(byte[] bytes) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

        cv.put("imageblob", bytes);
        Log.e("inserted", "inserted");
        getWritableDatabase().insert("Image", "imageblob", cv);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How I accomplished this with some of my projects, is I created an object that converts the image to a byte array (which eventually becomes your BLOB).

Inside this object is a static class that will simply decompress the byte array back into a bitmap. For you, you would want to call this everytime you have a BLOB.

Below you will find a excerpt of the code that I use to put the byte array back into a Bitmap.

```
public static final Bitmap ConvertByteArrayToBitmap(byte[] b){
    return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(b, 0, b.length);
}
```

Unfortunately I dont have an answer for the second half of your question.